# Showing $|G|=p^r \Rightarrow |G| \equiv |Z(G)| \pmod{p}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, finite-groups, p-groups

If $|G|=p^r$, then $|G| \equiv |Z(G)| \pmod{p}$

---

I think it's enough to show that $\sum_{|o(x)>1|}|G:st(x)|=np, n\in\mathbb{N}$  and use the proposal $|G|=|Z(G)|+ \sum_{|o(x)>1|}|G:st(G)|, $ then we get  $|G| \equiv |Z(G)| \pmod{p}$

(Here $st(x)$ is the stabilizer of $x$, and $o(x)$ is the orbit of $x$.)

Now because $|G|=|st(x)|| o(x)|$ we get that $|st(x)|$ divides the order of $G$, so it must divide $p^r$, and we can say it's of the form $p^m, m< r$, hence it will also divide $p^{r-1}$

Now  $\sum_{|o(x)>1|}|G:st(x)|=\frac{p^r}{p^{m_1}}+\dots +\frac{p^r}{p^{m_n}}=p\left(\frac{p^{r-1}}{p^{m_1}}+\dots +\frac{p^{r-1}}{p^{m_n}}\right)=pn$

Is this correct, is there an easier and more intuitive way to prove it?

Comment: There is likely something you're stating incorrectly as this problem is much easier. Recall that for finite groups, the order of a subgroup divides the order of the group. So in particular, $Z(G)$ is also a $p$-group. Therefore, $|Z(G)|$ is divisible by $p$ as well. So of course, $|G| = |Z(G)| = 0 \  (\text{mod} \ p) $

Comment: @Dionel Jaime what if the centre is just the identity? We should exclude this case or not ?

Comment: @DionelJaime That argument only works if you know the center of a $p$-group is nontrivial. And proving that is essentially equivalent to this problem.

Comment: And by the way, searching in the net "proving that a p group has non trivial centre" shows plenty of solutions. It is a standard result.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Agreed. In which case, I second what Thomas said. And add that the problem is now no longer as easy but is still a standard result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We want to prove that if $|G|=p^n$ then $p||Z(G)$.

If $G=Z(G)$ we're done so assume $G\neq Z(G)$. By the class equation we get:

$|G|=|Z(G)|+\sum|G:C_G(g_i)|$ for every $g_i\not\in Z(G)$. $p||G:C_G(gi)|$ and also $p||G|$ so by isolating $|Z(G)|$ we see that $p||Z(G)|$.